# A modern Java commons framework

Tags: java, libraries, guava

Does anybody know of a good common frameworks for Java that has common but tedious utility methods that do things like...

```
ObjectUtil.equalsOrBothNull(obj1,obj2)

FormatUtil.formatName(String firstName String middleName, String lastName) 

AddressUtil.formatAddress(address)
```

etc...

It seems like I always end up re-implementing these sorts of classes.  Guava-libraries is the closest thing I have found.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: formatName() and formatAddress() would be highly locale dependent, even the signature. In many cultures there isn't a firstName/lastName differentiation, or there's a firstName/familyName/lastName or firstName/generationName/lastName or ... and all those variations usually have non-trivial rules on how to write them. And once you start adding titles, then it's going to get really complicated. All in all that would probably be worth a library in its own right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a lot of utilities that you might find helpful.  I use that library in most of my projects.  [This page](http://commons.apache.org/lang/userguide.html) has a basic overview of the different classes.  StringUtils is the one that I use most, but many of the others have been handy once or twice.  ObjectUtils has the null-safe `equals` method you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for Commons Lang (and Commons IO). The OP asked for a "modern" library, I suppose that means support for generics and annotations. Not an issue for Commons Lang (not there, but not needed), but Commons Collections is getting a bit dusty without generics.

Comment: @Thilo: There's a generic-ised port of Commons Collections at http://larvalabs.com/collections/

Comment: The next versions of nearly all commons components are going to be genericised, just so you know

Answer (score 4):

You may also find hamcrest useful.

http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/

Here is the tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial